# When will WordPress Answers Move out of Beta?

Tags: discussion

I found that WordPress SE is staying in Beta for more than 4 months! That's an awfully long period.

When it will move out from Beta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, there's no *harm* in being in public beta, because there are no real restrictions on the site -- it is fully functional.

Generally we look for metrics of "excellent" on the site proposal dashboard before moving a site out of public beta:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers

If you'd like to come out sooner, promote the site! [Share links to great questions and answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/), and generally let other WordPress gurus know about it.

And, as Jan pointed out in a comment -- get out there and [vote early and often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)!

Comment: And the most important metric is users: we need so many +200 users because they can participate in keeping the site clean. So vote! Not only on answers, but also on questions. You have 30 votes per day (and get [a badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/57/suffrage) when your spend all of them), so go out and vote! Or stay in and vote, if you don't have mobile internet...